# How to parse multiple set-cookies using node.js solution?

Tags: node.js, cookies, http-headers, node-fetch

I am running into a problem where the api is returning multiple cookies and `node-fetch` is only returning a single `set-cookie`.

#### Retrieve

```
res.headers.get('set-cookie') // Only the first cookie
```

#### Actual Response

```
set-cookie: 1
set-cookie: 2
set-cookie: 3
```

The problem is well documented and answered, not work arounds though. Is there a way to convert the request so that I can somehow read the other headers of the same key?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps access the list of raw response headers with `(response.headers as any).raw()["set-cookie"]` and parse the result?

Comment: @IronMan appears to be working, thanks mate!